# SQL Server 2008 and HashBytes

Tags: sql-server-2008, hash, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

I have quite a large nvarchar which I wish to pass to the HashBytes function.
I get the error:

> "String or binary would be truncated.
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'colname', tbale 'table';
>   column does not allow nulls. UPDATE
>   fails. The statement has been
>   terminated."

Being ever resourceful, I discovered this was due to the HashBytes function having a maximum limit of 8000 bytes. Further searching showed me a 'solution' where my large varchar would be divided and hashed seperately and then later combined with this user defined function:

```
function [dbo].[udfLargeHashTable] (@algorithm nvarchar(4), @InputDataString varchar(MAX))
RETURNS varbinary(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @Index int,
    @InputDataLength int,
    @ReturnSum varbinary(max),
    @InputData varbinary(max)

SET @ReturnSum = 0
SET @Index = 1
SET @InputData = convert(binary,@InputDataString)
SET @InputDataLength = DATALENGTH(@InputData)

WHILE @Index <= @InputDataLength
BEGIN
    SET @ReturnSum = @ReturnSum + HASHBYTES(@algorithm, SUBSTRING(@InputData, @Index, 8000))
    SET @Index = @Index + 8000
END
RETURN @ReturnSum
END
```

which I call with:

```
set @ReportDefinitionHash=convert(int,dbo.[udfLargeHashTable]('SHA1',@ReportDefinitionForLookup))
```

Where @ReportDefinitionHash is int, and @ReportDefinitionForLookup is the varchar

Passing a simple char like 'test' produces a different int with my UDF than a normal call to HashBytes would produce.

Any advice on this issue?

Comment: Basically, you don't want to aggregate your hash string and so the return type should be varbinary(20). Then, there's try to run the following: `select hashbytes('sha1', 'test'), hashbytes('sha1', N'test')` (you're in for a big surprise) :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use this function (taken from [Hashing large data strings with a User Defined Function](http://sqlservernation.com/blogs/howtos/archive/2009/03/15/hashing-large-data-strings.aspx)):

```
create function dbo.fn_hashbytesMAX
    ( @string  nvarchar(max)
    , @Algo    varchar(10)
    )
    returns varbinary(20)
as
/************************************************************
*
*    Author:        Brandon Galderisi
*    Last modified: 15-SEP-2009 (by Denis)
*    Purpose:       uses the system function hashbytes as well
*                   as sys.fn_varbintohexstr to split an 
*                   nvarchar(max) string and hash in 8000 byte 
*                   chunks hashing each 8000 byte chunk,,
*                   getting the 40 byte output, streaming each 
*                   40 byte output into a string then hashing 
*                   that string.
*
*************************************************************/
begin
     declare    @concat       nvarchar(max)
               ,@NumHash      int
               ,@HASH         varbinary(20)
     set @NumHash = ceiling((datalength(@string)/2)/(4000.0))
    /* HashBytes only supports 8000 bytes so split the string if it is larger */
    if @NumHash>1
    begin
                                                        -- # * 4000 character strings
          ;with a as (select 1 as n union all select 1) -- 2 
               ,b as (select 1 as n from a ,a a1)       -- 4
               ,c as (select 1 as n from b ,b b1)       -- 16
               ,d as (select 1 as n from c ,c c1)       -- 256
               ,e as (select 1 as n from d ,d d1)       -- 65,536
               ,f as (select 1 as n from e ,e e1)       -- 4,294,967,296 = 17+ TRILLION characters
               ,factored as (select row_number() over (order by n) rn from f)
               ,factors as (select rn,(rn*4000)+1 factor from factored)

          select @concat = cast((
          select right(sys.fn_varbintohexstr
                         (
                         hashbytes(@Algo, substring(@string, factor - 4000, 4000))
                         )
                      , 40) + ''
          from Factors
          where rn <= @NumHash
          for xml path('')
          ) as nvarchar(max))


          set @HASH = dbo.fn_hashbytesMAX(@concat ,@Algo)
    end
     else
     begin
          set @HASH = convert(varbinary(20), hashbytes(@Algo, @string))
     end

return @HASH
end
```

And the results are as following:

```
select 
 hashbytes('sha1', N'test') --native function with nvarchar input
,hashbytes('sha1', 'test') --native function with varchar input 
,dbo.fn_hashbytesMAX('test', 'sha1') --Galderisi's function which casts to nvarchar input
,dbo.fnGetHash('sha1', 'test') --your function
```

Output:

```
0x87F8ED9157125FFC4DA9E06A7B8011AD80A53FE1  
0xA94A8FE5CCB19BA61C4C0873D391E987982FBBD3  
0x87F8ED9157125FFC4DA9E06A7B8011AD80A53FE1   
0x00000000AE6DBA4E0F767D06A97038B0C24ED720662ED9F1
```

Comment: I think there's a bug here. Calling `dbo.fn_hashbytesMAX()` with large values results in the same hash. Looks to me that the `@string` parameter type needs to be `nvarchar(max)` rather than `varchar(max)`, otherwise halving the `datalength()` result doesn't make sense. As it is, `datalength(@string)/2` means it's only hashing half as many substrings as it should.

Comment: I see originally the function provided was for `nvarchar(max)` input and was changed. Anyone using this should either change the `@string` datatype to `nvarchar(max)` or change the code to work correctly (which probably means change other nvarchar to varchar and removing the `/2`, but you'd want to test)

Comment: I've edited the answer as per my previous comments - now takes and computes using nvarchar. Won't output same value as hashbytes() if passed a varchar value as the argument is first cast to nvarchar. Changed to return varbinary so calling with md5 algorithm returns correct length.

Comment: Please see my answer below for a modified version of this solution that can be used with persisted computed columns.

Answer (score 13):

If you can't create a function and have to use something that already exists in the DB:

```
sys.fn_repl_hash_binary
```

can be made to work using the syntax:

```
sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(cast('some really long string' as varbinary(max)))
```

Taken from: http://www.sqlnotes.info/2012/01/16/generate-md5-value-from-big-data/

Comment: NB: only available from SQL Server 2008 onwards

Comment: Won't work if you have utf-8 data - `NVARCHAR` string

Comment: SQL Server doesn't use utf-8 strings. I had no problems with NVARCHAR strings.

Answer (score 6):

I've taken the accepted answer, and modified it a bit with the following improvements:

1. no longer recursive function
2. now schema bound
3. no longer relying on undocumented stored procedures
4. two versions: one for nvarchar, one for varchar
5. returns same data size as HASHBYTES, leaving it up to the end user to convert to smaller based on algorithm used. This allows the functions to support future algorithms with larger data returns.

With these changes, *the functions can now be used in persisted computed columns* as they are now marked deterministic when created.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnHashBytesNVARCHARMAX
(
    @Algorithm VARCHAR(10),
    @Text NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARBINARY(8000)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumHash INT;
    DECLARE @HASH VARBINARY(8000);
    SET @NumHash = CEILING(DATALENGTH(@Text) / (8000.0));
    /* HashBytes only supports 8000 bytes so split the string if it is larger */
    WHILE @NumHash > 1
    BEGIN
        -- # * 4000 character strings
        WITH a AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 2 
        b AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM a, a a1),       -- 4
        c AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM b, b b1),       -- 16
        d AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM c, c c1),       -- 256
        e AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM d, d d1),       -- 65,536
        f AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM e, e e1),       -- 4,294,967,296 = 17+ TRILLION characters
        factored AS
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) rn FROM f),
        factors AS
        (SELECT rn, (rn * 4000) + 1 factor FROM factored)
        SELECT  @Text = CAST
            (
                (
                    SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, SUBSTRING(@Text, factor - 4000, 4000)), 1)
                    FROM    factors
                    WHERE   rn <= @NumHash
                    FOR XML PATH('')
                ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
            );

        SET @NumHash = CEILING(DATALENGTH(@Text) / (8000.0));
    END;
    SET @HASH = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8000), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, @Text));
    RETURN @HASH;
END;

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnHashBytesVARCHARMAX
(
    @Algorithm VARCHAR(10),
    @Text VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARBINARY(8000)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @NumHash INT;
    DECLARE @HASH VARBINARY(8000);
    SET @NumHash = CEILING(DATALENGTH(@Text) / (8000.0));
    /* HashBytes only supports 8000 bytes so split the string if it is larger */
    WHILE @NumHash > 1
    BEGIN
        -- # * 4000 character strings
        WITH a AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n UNION ALL SELECT 1), -- 2 
        b AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM a, a a1),       -- 4
        c AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM b, b b1),       -- 16
        d AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM c, c c1),       -- 256
        e AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM d, d d1),       -- 65,536
        f AS
        (SELECT 1 AS n FROM e, e e1),       -- 4,294,967,296 = 17+ TRILLION characters
        factored AS
        (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY n) rn FROM f),
        factors AS
        (SELECT rn, (rn * 8000) + 1 factor FROM factored)
        SELECT  @Text = CAST
        (
            (
                SELECT  CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, SUBSTRING(@Text, factor - 8000, 8000)), 1)
                FROM    factors
                WHERE   rn <= @NumHash
                FOR XML PATH('')
            ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
        );

        SET @NumHash = CEILING(DATALENGTH(@Text) / (8000.0));
    END;
    SET @HASH = CONVERT(VARBINARY(8000), HASHBYTES(@Algorithm, @Text));
    RETURN @HASH;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a SQL CLR function:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
public static SqlBinary BigHashBytes(SqlString algorithm, SqlString data)
{
    var algo = HashAlgorithm.Create(algorithm.Value);

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.Value);

    return new SqlBinary(algo.ComputeHash(bytes));
}
```

And then it can be called in SQL like this:

```
--these return the same value
select HASHBYTES('md5', 'test stuff')
select dbo.BigHashBytes('md5', 'test stuff')
```

The `BigHashBytes` is only necessary if the length would be over 8k.

Comment: 1) String data in SQL Server is stored as UTF-16 Little Endian, which equates to "Unicode" in .NET. 2) You don't need to mess with `Encoding.<encoding_name>` since SqlString can just give you the Unicode byte[] via [SqlString.GetUnicodeBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlstring.getunicodebytes.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

tested and working
select master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(someVarbinaryMaxValue)
moreover not complicated :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be used as function body, too:

```
DECLARE @A NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'test'

DECLARE @res VARBINARY(MAX) = 0x
DECLARE @position INT = 1
        ,@len INT = DATALENGTH(@A)

WHILE 1 = 1
BEGIN
    SET @res = @res + HASHBYTES('SHA2_256', SUBSTRING(@A, @position, 4000))
    SET @position = @position+4000
    IF @Position > @len 
        BREAK
END

SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256',@res)
```

The idea si to `HASH` each `4000` part of the `NVARCHAR(MAX)` string and concatanate the results. Then to `HASH` the latter result.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the easiest solution is to write a recursive hashing algorithm that parses the input text value into sub `varchar(8000)` segments.
I arbitrarily chose to slice the input string into 7500 character segments
The hashing algorithm returns a `varbinary(20)` which can easily be converted into a `varchar(20)`

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[BigHash]
(   
    @TextValue nvarchar(max)
)

RETURNS varbinary(20)

AS
BEGIN

    if @TextValue = null
        return hashbytes('SHA1', 'null')


    Declare @FirstPart as varchar(7500)
    Declare @Remainder as varchar(max)

    Declare @RemainderHash as varbinary(20)
    Declare @BinaryValue as varbinary(20)

    Declare @TextLength as integer


    Set @TextLength = len(@TextValue)

    if @TextLength > 7500
        Begin
            Set @FirstPart = substring(@TextValue, 1, 7500)         

            Set @Remainder = substring(@TextValue, 7501, @TextLength - 7500)        

            Set @RemainderHash = dbo.BigHash(@Remainder)

            Set @BinaryValue = hashbytes('SHA1', @FirstPart + convert( varchar(20), @RemainderHash, 2 ))

            return @BinaryValue

        End
    else
        Begin
            Set @FirstPart = substring(@TextValue, 1, @TextLength)                      
            Set @BinaryValue = hashbytes('SHA1', @FirstPart)

            return @BinaryValue
        End


    return null

END
```