# Calculating MD5 HashBytes for Nvarchar(max) column is possible in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, hash, md5

I have a table with a column data type nvarchar(max), the column will have data more than 8000 characters.

```
mytext navarchar(max)
```

I want to calculate hash value of that column, I am using the following code in MS SQL 2008/R2

```
select HASHBYTES('md5',column_name)
```

But I am getting error as,

```
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Is that possible to calculate hash value in nvarchar(max) field in sql query.

Or is there any other ways to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: MSDN Documentation for [`HASHBYTES`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415(v=sql.105).aspx), says `Allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes` hence sorry you are out of luck :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 and HashBytes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717977/sql-server-2008-and-hashbytes)

Comment: With a .Net CLR, it works fine with long string

Answer (score 1):

Allowed input values are limited to 8000 bytes as was mentioned.

Try:

`select master.sys.fn_repl_hash_binary(cast(column_name as varbinary(max)))`

For this operation you have to disable FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms:
http://blog.aggregatedintelligence.com/2007/10/fips-validated-cryptographic-algorithms.html

Comment: please add tags