# String or binary data would be truncated on SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to have a checksum of the joined rows values of a table. So when i try this query, i receive the error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 1, String or binary data would be
>   truncated

```
SELECT TOP 10000 A.AR_Ref,
(SELECT HASHBYTES('md5',convert(varbinary(max),
        (SELECT [AR_Ref],[AC_Categorie],[AC_PrixVen],[AC_Coef],[AC_PrixTTC],
                [AC_Arrondi],[AC_QteMont],[EG_Champ],[AC_PrixDev],
                [AC_Devise],[CT_Num],[AC_Remise],[AC_Calcul],[AC_TypeRem],
                [AC_RefClient],[AC_CoefNouv],[AC_PrixVenNouv],
                [AC_PrixDevNouv],[AC_RemiseNouv],[AC_DateApplication] 
         FROM F_ARTCLIENT AC 
         WHERE AC.AR_Ref = A.AR_Ref AND AC_Categorie BETWEEN 1 AND 14 
         FOR XML AUTO)))) AS cscli
FROM F_ARTICLE A
```

EDIT: I could resolve my probleme by using a special function (link provided by  Giorgos Betsos in the comments)

Comment: Check all fields data type and compare value also.

Comment: Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3717977/sql-server-2008-and-hashbytes) question. If it answers your problem, then this post should be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Please add table DDL

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to insert data is longer than your defined length of data type. This function convert(varbinary(max)) can be conflicting your data size.